# Angular Material datatable show [object Object]

Tags: javascript, angular, express, datatable, angular-datatables

I'm trying to implement datatable component using Express and Firebase DB.

Here's how my service request data

```
gettext() {
  return this.http.get<nomchamp[]>(this.url)
      .map(res => { console.log(res); return res });
}
```

console.log prints :

```
[{…}]
       0: {text: "testoooo"}
       length: 1__proto__: Array(0)
```

I have created a model

```
export interface nomchamp {
    text: String;
}
```

Here's my datatable component

```
export class DatatableComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dataService: AjouttextService) { }
  data = [];

  displayedColumns = ['text'];
  dataSource = new UserDataSource(this.dataService);
  ;

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
  }



  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
export class UserDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
  constructor(private dataService: AjouttextService) {
    super();
  }
  connect(): Observable<nomchamp[]> {
    return this.dataService.gettext()
  }
  disconnect() { }
}
```

And html:

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
          The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="text">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>



    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
</div>
```

In my express post route I push an object of data then I call it in the get route

```
router
  .route("/")
  .get(function (req, res, err) {

    // Get a database reference to our posts
    var db = admin.database();
    var ref = db.ref("/");

    // Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
    ref.on("value", function (snapshot) {
      res.send(snapshot.val());

      console.log(snapshot.val());
    }, function (errorObject) {
      console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    });
  });

router
  .route("/")
  .post(function (req, res, err) {

    // Get a database reference to our posts
    var db = admin.database();
    var ref = db.ref("/");

    // Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
    ref.set(
      [{ text: "testoooo" }]
    );
  });
```

In my datatable I get this preview

```
[object Object]
```

[image]

I have found the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48623654/angular-datatable-results-error-trying-to-diff-object-object-only-arrays-a) but the format of received data is not the same as in question because I don't have an array
Here's what postman send

```
[
      {
          "text": "testoooo"
      }
]
```

Comment: Are you looking for `["tesstooo"]` ?

Comment: yes , And I will have multiple values for exemple ["testooo","blabla","..."]

Comment: Considering your strings are already in an array called `tab`, then just `ref.push().set({nomchamp: tab})`, I don't understand what you're looking for ?

Comment: I have updated my post

Comment: `text: String;` May be your model is wrong ? Because it seems you want a String here. And postman send an array. Try to change your model.

Comment: Are you using JSON middleware with express?  Are you posting as JSON?  From `[object Object]` it looks like your object is getting converted to a string somewhere.  What exactly are the results in angular, in express, and in the firebase console after each step?

Comment: Post your angular component and template html?

Comment: I have made some changes on get server route, now I get  an array , but angular datatable take the object as an array value so I get again `object Object`

Comment: @AdamCox I have added html and component

Comment: @infodev please review my example of how to use observable (i.e. http) to assign return data to the material table component... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yx7eu1?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to assign/pass data from http, or any other service that returns an observable, to the Angular Material Table Component (or other presentation control) by subscribing.  See my stackblitz example:  [Presenting Tabular Data Sets Using Angular Material Table Component and Observable](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yx7eu1?file=README.md).